# How do I enable DPMS (console blanking)?

Tags: linux, console, dpms

When I log directly into a console /dev/tty1 - 6 and am idle for a while or even if I haven't logged in, I would like the screen to poweroff.

I am using xset +dpms dpms n n n to set during my X Session, but am unsure how to do it in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# setterm --blank <minutes>
```

or permanently a kernel parameter in grub.cfg:

```
consoleblank=600
```

Comment: Beware, as it stays blank, even if you press the keyboard and move the mouse or even turn the screen off and on again. At least here, that was the case. I had to shut down and reboot, to get back to normal. (This is a Gentoo home server with no graphical X or the like to switch to.)